# Tikz how to draw a line to rectangle split

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing an ER-diagram and would like to show the relationships between tables.

[image]

I managed to create the tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\tikzset{
  outernode/.style={draw,ultra thick,inner sep=0},
  innernode/.style={inner sep=.3333em,draw,rectangle split}
}
\newcommand\innernode[2]{\tikz\node[innernode,rectangle split parts=#1]{#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) [outernode]
       { \innernode 2 {sco\_groups \nodepart{second} id} } ;
  \node (2) [below= 1cm of 1.south east, anchor=north west, outernode]
       { \innernode 3 {sco\_index \nodepart{second} tid \nodepart{third} sco\_id} } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But don't know, how to create the line, uniting them (I marked it with red).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update:

I don't think using a `\tikz \node` (earlier solution -- below) is what you should be using.
At least I could not figure out how to get access to particular `nodepart` with that method.  So there are three updates here:

- As per Jake's suggestions, it is easier to just simply use `(1.south) |- (2.two west)` to draw the line shown in red.  Now to make a connection to the `sco_id` you can just access the side of this node via `(2.three west)`.
- The `\innernode` TeX *macro* has been eliminated.
- The `innernode` *style* has been enhanced to accept an additional parameter to allow you to specify the number of inner nodes.

So, now you can easily access any `nodepart` you desire:

[image]

---

You can connect them via `(1.south) -- ($(1.south |- 2.west)$) -- (2.west)`:

[image]

---

### Code: Updated

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}

\tikzset{
  outernode/.style={draw,ultra thick, inner sep=0},
  innernode/.style={inner sep=.3333em, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [outernode] (1)
        [innernode=2] { sco\_groups \nodepart{second} id} ;

    \node[below=1cm of 1.south east, anchor=north west, outernode] (2) 
        [innernode=3] {
            sco\_index 
            \nodepart{second} tid
            \nodepart{third} sco\_id
    };
    
    \draw [blue, ultra thick]  (1.-40)   |- (2.one west);
    \draw [red,  ultra thick]  
            (1.south)    node [below left, black] {$1$} |- 
            (2.two west) node [above left, black] {$n$};
    \draw [olive,   ultra thick]  (1.-140)   |- (2.three west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Original

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  outernode/.style={draw,ultra thick,inner sep=0},
  innernode/.style={inner sep=.3333em,draw,rectangle split}
}
\newcommand\innernode[2]{\tikz\node[innernode,rectangle split parts=#1]{#2};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) [outernode]
       { \innernode 2 {sco\_groups \nodepart{second} id} } ;
  \node (2) [below= 1cm of 1.south east, anchor=north west, outernode]
       { \innernode 3 {sco\_index \nodepart{second} tid \nodepart{third} sco\_id} } ;

\draw [red, ultra thick] 
        (1.south) node [below left, black] {$1$} -- 
        ($(1.south |- 2.west)$) -- 
        (2.west) node [above left, black] {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you, plz, add the code, joining id with sco_id? So I could join it with the bottom part of the split.

Comment: @user4035 Change `(2.west)` to `(2.three west)` in the last `\draw` command.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Why not just use `(1.south) |- (2.west)`?

Comment: @user4035: Have updated solution. Please let me know if the older solution has any value to you, otherwise I will remove that.

Comment: It has a great value. Plz, don't remove.